# Range Minimum Query above a constant value

Tags: tree, persistent, segment, rmq

> Given an array of n elements . Find minimum value of element in range [l...r] such that a[k]> p . ( l<=k<=r  and  p varies with each l and r).

Is there any solution that works in log(N)?

Comment: Make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your work, and ask a specific question.

Comment: Getting you through your class is Your task not Ours. That is the reason you go to school.

Answer (score 0):

PS : I thought of a solution to find(k) number of elements that are less than <= p. And then find the k+1th element in range if the array is sorted.but I am stuck at point update operation for the persistent segment tree for finding the k+1 th element.